# Clojure Equality of Symbols

Tags: clojure, symbols, equality

I'm having trouble with a clojure project, and I cannot seem to find an answer.  I am trying to compare two symbols:

```
'x  'y
```

But when I use:

```
(= ('x 'y))
```

It returns true.  The same with:

```
(identical? 'x 'y)
```

I have found that identical compares memory addresses, but I have not found why 'x and 'y when compared return true?  I have not seen a question like this, most of the other posts compare numbers.

Comment: In `(= ('x 'y))` what are you comparing `('x 'y)` to? Because `(= 'x 'y)` returns false.

Comment: Ahhh, it seems my syntax was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: You're calling 'x as a function. Symbols, like keywords, implement IFn to look themselves up in maps (and return nil when passed something other than a map).

Answer (score 9):

You are comparing a list of symbols to nothing. If you only pass one argument to =, it returns true by default. Just remove the parentheses around the symbols and then you'll be comparing the symbols themselves. `(= 'x 'y)`.

Comment: The list isn't quoted, so it's actually invoking 'x as a function (see marivas' answer).

Answer (score 6):

```
(= nil) ; => true

('x 'y) ; => nil

('x #{'x}) ; => 'x

('x #{'z} :one) ; => :one

(instance? clojure.lang.IFn 'x) ; => true
```

Comment: nothing is best that autoexplain code and especially my english is very poor ;-) sorry !!!